# Writing (and not) to global variable in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables, python-internals

Coming from much less dynamic C++, I have some trouble understanding the behaviour of this Python (2.7) code.

*Note:* I am aware that this is bad programming style / evil, but I would like to understand it non the less.

```
vals = [1,2,3]

def f():
    vals[0] = 5
    print 'inside', vals

print 'outside', vals
f()
print 'outside', vals
```

This code runs without error, and `f` manipulates the (seemingly) global list. This is contrary to my prior understanding that global variables that are to be manipulated (and not only read) in a function must be declared as `global ...`.

On the other hand, if I replace `vals[0] = 5` with `vals += [5,6]`, execution fails with an `UnboundLocalError` unless I add a `global vals` to `f`. This is what I would have expected to happen in the first case as well.

Could you explain this behaviour?

Why can I manipulate `vals` in the first case? Why does the second type of manipulation fail while the first does not?

**Update:**
It was remarked in a comment that `vals.extend(...)` works without `global`. This adds to my confusion - why is `+=` treated differently from a call to `extend`?

Comment: I'm not really into python, but does it allow *reading* globals without a "global" declaration? I think the explanation may be that assignment to `vals[0]` doesn't *assign* to `vals` (it's still the same array), so doing `vals[0]=5` is a kind of *reading*.

Comment: I think it has to do with changing which object the variable references. What I don't get is why `vals.extend([5, 6])` will work but `vals += [5, 6]` won't, when the two are essentially the same when it comes to lists.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko It does allow reading without global statement. Coming from a world of const-correctness, it baffles me that two value-changing operations seem to be treated completely differently.

Comment: @Volatility: Excellent point! I didn't try that. Adds to my confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`global` is only needed when you are trying to change the object which the variable references. Because `vals[0] = 5` changes the actual object rather than the reference, no error is raised. However, with `vals += [5, 6]`, the interpreter tries to find a local variable because it can't change the global variable.

The confusing thing is that using the `+=` operator with list modifies the original list, like `vals[0] = 5`. And whereas `vals += [5, 6]` fails, `vals.extend([5, 6])` works. We can enlist the help of [`dis.dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.dis) to lend us some clues.

```
>>> def a(): v[0] = 1
>>> def b(): v += [1]
>>> def c(): v.extend([1])
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(a)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (v)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
              9 STORE_SUBSCR        
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(b)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (v)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 BUILD_LIST               1
              9 INPLACE_ADD         
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (v)
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE        
d
>>> dis.dis(c)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (v)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (extend)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 BUILD_LIST               1
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             15 POP_TOP             
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

We can see that functions `a` and `c` use `LOAD_GLOBAL`, whereas `b` tries to use `LOAD_FAST`. We can see now why using `+=` won't work - the interpreter tries to load `v` as a local variable because of it's default behaviour with in-place addition. Because it can't know whether `v` is a list or not, it essentially assumes that the line means the same as `v = v + [1]`.

Comment: Great answer! In C++ treating += as copy plus add would have severe performance implications. Does it in Python? Is extend faster?

Comment: @DCS What's "copy plus add"? In Python, the `.` operator carries some overhead, so `extend` is very slightly slower. `+=` is practically the same as `extend` though when you're not doing it a million times over.

Comment: Understood. In C++, A=A+C on classes like vector (=list) can easily trigger an unnecessary duplication of A, if used without care.

Answer (score 2):

`global` is needed when you want to assign to a variable in the outer scope. If you don't use `global`, Python will consider `vals` as a local variable when doing assignments.

`+=` is an assignment (an [augmented assignment](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/)) and `vals += [5, 6]` is equivalent to reading `vals`, then append `[5, 6]` to that value and assign the resulting list back to the original `vals`. Because `vals += [5,6]` has no `global` statement, Python sees the assignment and treats `vals` as local. You didn't create a local variable called `vals` but you try to append to it and from here the `UnboundLocalError`.

But for reading it is not necessary to use `global`. The variable will be looked up locally first then, if it's not found in the local scope, it's looked up in the outer scope and so on. And since you are dealing with a reference type you get back a reference when you do the read. You can change the content of the object trough that reference.

That's why `.extend()` works (because it's called on the reference and acts on the object itself) while `vals += [5, 6]` fails (because `vals` is neither local nor marked `global`).

Here is a modified example to try out (using a local `vals` clears the `UnboundLocalError`):

```
vals = [1, 2, 3]

def f():
    vals = []
    vals += [5,6]
    print 'inside', vals

print 'outside', vals
f()
print 'outside', vals
```

Comment: I get your point that manipulating a list element is not an assignment. User Volatility remarked that calling extend on the list does work without global statement - I get that this is not an assignment as well. But why is += treated as assignment while extend is not?

Comment: @DCS: `extend()` is a method called on the reference you get back from the read. It appends to the existing object. Instead, `+=` is an assignment, and [augmented assignment](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/) actually. `vals += [5,6]` loads `vals`, then [5, 6] is added to it, and the resulting object is stored back in the original `vals`. It is here you have the problem. In this assignment to `vals` which is not declared as `global` and you haven't got a local one either.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, SomeList+=Val is actually treated like SomeList = SomeList+Val rather than an override of the extend method?

Comment: @DCS Essentially, yes. At least as far as syntax goes (it may actually get optimized to `blah.extend...` in a later stage, but that is after the error has been raised).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do not change object reference, Python will preserve global object. Compare

```
In [114]: vals = [1,2,3]

In [116]: id(vals)
Out[116]: 144255596

In [118]: def func():
    vals[0] = 5
    return id(vals)
   .....: 

In [119]: func()
Out[119]: 144255596

In [120]: def func_update():
    vals = vals
    return id(vals)
   .....: 

In [121]: func_update()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/homes/markg/<ipython-input-121-f1149c600a85> in <module>()
----> 1 func_update()

/homes/markg/<ipython-input-120-257ba6ff792a> in func_update()
      1 def func_update():
----> 2     vals = vals
      3     return id(vals)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'vals' referenced before assignment
```

The moment you try assignment, Python regards vals as local variable - and (oops) it's not there!